# NEO4J / Cypher: Create Node if a collection only has false result

Tags: neo4j, cypher

i have a COLLECT with true or false based on a validation query and i want to create **one** node if every result in the collection is false. How do i filter the Collection for this specific result?

```
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT(...))
```

[true] = Nothing happens

[false,true] = Nothing happens

[false] = Create new node

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `all()` or `none()` list predicate which will allow you to test every element of the list and return the appropriate boolean value.

```
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT(...)) as testList
WHERE all(val in testList WHERE val = false)
CREATE ...
```

Keep in mind that this will return `true` for an empty list, so you may want to add an additional predicate: `AND size(testList) > 0`